# best GPS location format for free location tracking map software?-

Tags: google-maps, gps, maps

I have a custom mobile application that is  spitting out this format for Map waypoint

YY-MM-DD-YY HH.MM XX.XXXXX,-YY.YYYYYYYYYYY

Is there a better format or standard for waypoints if want to use some free online sw to track multiple waypoints chronologically with google maps?

I know I can take the x and y and format it like this for a single point:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=XX.XXX,-YY.YYYY

But does Google have an API that will translate multiple points onto a map from a single file? Or is there some good free GPS mapping software or www site that would be easy to use with my file format or similar?

I see that there are free online sites that will take muliple  Latitude and Lognitude and display it on a map, but it does not appear to care for the timestamp.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NMEA is the navigation standard with a number of simple sentences for lat/lon information.  WPL (GPWPL in most cases) is probably the simplest sentence for you but you could probably get away with GLL.  http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm has a good guide to the sentence structure, and Google will lead you to thirty years of various data transformation utilities.  http://www.h-schmidt.net/NMEA/ is a solid file-based solution.

Google Earth 5.2 and above claim NMEA compatibility, but I haven't tested it.